# Nerd tree show full filename

Tags: plugin-nerdtree

In nerdtree as we go deeper filenames are hidden due to smaller width of tree window. Is there a fix to show full filename over the window which is currently highlighted in tree?

[image]

Comment: have no nerdtree but it may be possible with the normal vim linewrap:
http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Word_wrap_without_line_breaks but as always when some problem with nerdtree is coming up, i suggest reading this: http://vimcasts.org/blog/2013/01/oil-and-vinegar-split-windows-and-project-drawer/ and have a look at vinegar-vim

Comment: This is not exactly a solution to your question, but to see the full filename, I use Shift + A to maximize NERDTree over the whole screen (and then to minimize it to the side again).